# Where is a Viewpager example/tutorial code that works fine for everyone?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I've been looking for a while and I can not find a clear, straightforward ViewPager example that works. I think others are having the same problem and I want to know. I know there are other questions about them but I've tried the websites are they are either out of date or crash.

Comment: Which ones have you tried, and what specifically doesn't work with them? What problems are others having?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've been looking for a while and I can not find a clear, straightforward ViewPager example that works

Here is one that uses [`ViewPager` with a `FragmentPagerAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Fragments).

Here is one that is the same as the above, [with the addition of a `PagerTabStrip`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Indicator).

Here is one that uses [tabs in the action bar](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/TabPager) instead of a `PagerTabStrip`.

The gist of all is the same:

- Add a `ViewPager` to an activity layout
- Create some sort of `PagerAdapter` that will return the pages
- Attach the adapter to the pager

Comment: How do I just get the code JUST for the Viewpager because all the packages are separated and it's getting frustrating trying to get the code.

Comment: @JacobBrans: `ViewPager` is in the Android Support package, available from your SDK Manager.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you please have a look at my question regarding View pager
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895554/rendering-views-to-view-pager-optimized-way